# What is rdt_rcv(rcvpkt)/Λ in the given figure?

Tags: ipv4, ip, tcp, ipv6, ip-address

Please explain. I marked it in a red circle.

[image: It's marked in red color]

It's rounded in  red color.I got this from the book Computer networking a top down approach.Pg NUM 241.
Section 3.4
Rdt 3.0

Comment: I don't think the symbol below the line is a delta.

Comment: Ya it's not Delta but still I don't had a suitable key in keyboard for it

Comment: The `Λ` character is a Lambda (`U+039B`) that indicates the time period over which you are evaluating the expression.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The capital lambda 'Λ' is the "output alphabet" -- it's part of the notation for finite state machines, and is the set of possible outputs.  The trigger events of the transition come from the "input alphabet" (normally capital sigma 'Σ').  Transition events are listed above the line, the actions underneath.

See for example http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/home/mic/FiniteStateMachines1-slides.pdf

Or, on the subject of reliable data transmission http://www.nyu.edu/classes/jcf/CSCI-GA.2262-001_fa13/slides/session6/ReliableDataTransfer.pdf